# How to ignore/exclude folders with RecursiveDirectoryIterator?

Tags: php

I'm using `PharData` to create a tar package. It works fine but it includes a folder i don't want. How can I exclude a folder in the archive?

```
<?php
$dir = "/foobar/dir";
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir)
);

$phar = new PharData('/mytar.tar');
$phar->buildFromIterator($iterator, $dir);
$phar->compress(Phar::GZ);
unlink(realpath('/mytar.tar'));
```

The folder I want to ignore in the archive is `vendor` (`/foobar/dir/vendor`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `CallbackFilterIterator()` to filter the unwanted files and folders (not tested yet):

```
<?php
$dir = "/foobar/dir";
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir)
);
$filterIterator = new CallbackFilterIterator($iterator , function ($file) {
    return (strpos($file, "vendor/") === false);
});
$phar = new PharData('/mytar.tar');
$phar->buildFromIterator($filterIterator, $dir);
$phar->compress(Phar::GZ);
unlink(realpath('/mytar.tar'));
```